# OrderByDescending is causing my datagridview to not populate

Tags: c#, datasource

I want to order my list based on the column HitCount. When I append `OrderByDescending` to the end of the source, the DataGridView is no longer being populated. I can take it off and it works fine.

```
  var source = CapturedLogs.CapturedIpAddresses.OrderByDescending(x => x.HitCount);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = source;

  public static List<CapturedLog> CapturedIpAddresses{set;get;}

  internal class CapturedLog
  {
    public string IpAddress { set; get; }
    public int HitCount { set; get; }
    public bool IsRecordedInFirewall { set; get; }
    public bool IsWhiteListed { set; get; }

  }
```

When I add the `.OrderByDescending(x => x.HitCount);` the DataGridView doesn't populate.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `.OrderByDescending(...).ToList()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks), the `DataSource` property can only be set to an object of a type that implements `IList`, `IListSource`, `IBindingList`,  or `IBindingListView`.

When you simply append `.OrderByDescending()` and don't actually materialize the result, it returns an object of type `OrderedEnumerable`, which does *not* implement any of the interfaces mentioned above.

You need to change the type of `source` to something that implements of the supported interfaces. For example:

```
// List<CapturedLog>
var source = CapturedLogs.CapturedIpAddresses
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.HitCount)
    .ToList();

// CapturedLog[]
var source2 = CapturedLogs.CapturedIpAddresses
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.HitCount)
    .ToArray();

// BindingSource
var ordered = CapturedLogs.CapturedIpAddresses.OrderByDescending(x => x.HitCount);
var source3 = new BindingSource(ordered, null);
```